# Foundation XY grid full width for some cells

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am wondering wether is possible to set full width for some cells on Foundation 6.5 XY grid.

I am aware that the grid-container can be set to be **fluid** or **full** but my intention is to within one grid container to set some cells to be full width.

```
 <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x">
    <div class="cell small-12">
      Contained cell.
    </div>
    
    <div class="cell small-12 full-width-possible">
      Full width cell possible?
    </div>
    
    <div class="cell small-12">
      Contained cell.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I didn't find any other option than creating a separate full container.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `.small-12`, you are setting a cell to be 100% width.

So for fluid width I'd suggest you only wrap your cell that need to be contained in a `.grid-container` and the fluid ones without a `grid-container`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to have a nested cell a container with a width edge to edge of the viewport whilst its container remains at 1200px wide (of whatever Foundation default is).

An option you could try is using offsets. E.g.

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid-container full">
  <div class="grid-x">
    <div class="cell small-10 small-offset-1">
      Contained cell.
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-12">
      Full width cell possible?
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-10 small-offset-1">
      Contained cell.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @dom_ahdigital! 

This is certainly a solution that comes close to what I want, the problem is that using the offset approach I can never achieve the default width from Foundation (1200 in my case) as the width is relative to the full width of the viewport.